# TYPO3 6.1: Show / hide content elements in wizard depending on the chosen frontend / backend layout

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-6.1.x

is it possible to show / hide content element items in "new content element wizard" depending on the chosen frontend / backend layout of the current page by only using TSConf?

Thank you!

PS: I use TYPO3 6.1.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use the `[page|field = value]` condition in the TSconfig (either pageTS or userTS) to manipulate the number of items.
Those are defined in `mod.wizards.newContentElement.wizardItems.`. You can use the Web>Info module to have a look at the list of current items.

http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Conditions/Reference/Index.html#id41

The only real problem is, that you cannot check the overlay field from backend_layout_next up in the rootline that will affect the visible backend layout.
If you need that, then you will need to create a user function and use this as condition (same link as above, last section of the page). There you can calculate the effective backend layout and use this to compare (or evaluate even more complex scenarios, e.g. take user group into account, etc).